# Molecular orbital diagram of CO and charge localisation

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory

[MO diagram of CO](https://www.chemtube3d.com/orbitalsco/)

My question concerns the interpretation of the Molecular Orbital of CO. I think I find it clear how you build it but I have some concerns about how you rationalize it.

Particularly, from what I read the reason we envision carbon as being partially negatively charged in CO is that the HOMO of the molecule lies closer to the carbon orbitals. However, from the MO diagram, it can be seen that the p-oxygen orbitals are closer to the HOMO than both of the orbitals of carbon.

My question is: what we use as a benchmark to judge that the HOMO is closer in to energy carbon: are we looking at average energy or something completely different and I completely misinterpreted the argument?

Comment: I would be inclined to rationalise this using resonance rather than MO diagrams. The lone pair on the O can be donated to make a triple bond with a formal negative charge on the C and a formal positive charge on the O. See https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Book%3A_Chem1_(Lower)/09%3A_Chemical_Bonding_and_Molecular_Structure/9.04%3A_Polar_Covalence for a brief discussion of this

Comment: CO is a terribly complex molecule. There is a pen and paper approach you can go for qualitatively determining a trend. I'm confident that is not possible without the proper mathematical/computational tools. I have demonstrated the first approach here: [How to rationalise with MO theory that CO is a two-electron donor through carbon?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/51262/4945) I hope that this question will answer your query: [How can the dipole moment of carbon monoxide be rationalised by molecular orbital theory?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/30797/4945)